# file handling in c is not working

Tags: c, file

I do not know what is happening in this very basic code but the output says that the program has stopped working. Can anyone help me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main()
{
    FILE *ptr;
    double y=9.0;
    double x;

    ptr=fopen("test.csv","w");
    fprintf(ptr,"%lf",y);
    fclose(ptr);

    ptr=fopen("test.csv","r");
    fscanf("%lf",&x);
    printf("%lf",x);
    fclose(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Do basic debugging and error checking for yourself before getting others to debug for you. Use a debugger. Check the return value of each function call.

Comment: Look at the man page for fscanf()... you have an error...

Comment: `fscanf("%lf",&x)` --> `fscanf(ptr,"%lf",&x)`

Comment: oh right! I'm very sorry. Thank you.

Comment: In addition to fixing fscanf(), you should take @kaylum advise too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, is the correct piece of code, you need to change your `scanf` statement

```
include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main()
{

FILE *ptr;
double y=9.0;
double x;

ptr=fopen("test.csv","w");
fprintf(ptr,"%lf",y);
fclose(ptr);

ptr=fopen("test.csv","r");
fscanf(ptr,"%lf",&x);
printf("%lf",x);
fclose(ptr);
}
```